# pgrep command not returning PID

Tags: linux

I am trying to find the PID of a process (motion_sensor.py), but pgrep returns nothing. Why does it not return the process id?

```
pgrep -u www-data motion_sensor.py
```

ps -ef | grep "motion_sensor" returns

```
root      7149     1 93 Apr25 ?        15:59:08 python motion_sensor.py
www-data 31872 23531  0 14:09 ?        00:00:00 sh -c sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/PiControl/motion_sensor.py
root     31873 31872  0 14:09 ?        00:00:00 sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/PiControl/motion_sensor.py
root     31874 31873 47 14:09 ?        00:14:30 python /home/pi/Desktop/PiControl/motion_sensor.py
pi       32645 32202  0 14:39 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto motion_sensor.py
```

Comment: `motion_sensor.py` is not a name of a process. You probably want `python` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally `pgrep` applies the search pattern to process names. The process name in this case is `python` and not `motion_sensor.py`. If you want to grep for the full path rather than just the process name you need to pass `-f`:

```
pgrep -u www-data -f motion_sensor.py
```

Check [`man pgrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep)

Answer (score 0):

the requirement is to find out PID of a process,
So you can try :

ps aux | grep www-data motion_sensor.py